# Summation in inner product problem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $B=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis. I'm given that $v$ can be expressed as $v=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jv_j $.

My task is to then show that $v=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,v\rangle v_i$.

So far I have said the following:

Taking the inner product with $v_i$ gives $$\langle v_i,v \rangle=\left\langle v_i, \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j v_j\right\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j \langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j \delta_{ij}$$

The solution then says $$\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j \delta_{ij}=\lambda_i$$

Could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: The only term that survives the summation is the term i=j, due to the nature of the dirac delta.

Comment: So surely that would give $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j \delta_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_i=n\lambda_i$?

Comment: Nope it will give you: $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j\delta_{ij} =\lambda_1\delta_{i1}+\lambda_2\delta_{i2}+\dots +\lambda_i\delta_{ii}+\dots + \lambda_n\delta_{in}$$ $$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\lambda_1\cdot 0+\lambda_2\cdot 0+\dots +\lambda_i\cdot 1+\dots + \lambda_n\cdot 0$$

Comment: Oh that makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome (: